# Why is this switch case returning a double even though it is an int?

Tags: c#, .net-core, switch-statement

Given following code:

```cs
object value = header.DataContentType switch
{
    DataContentType.DOUBLE => (double)BitConverter.ToDouble(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.FLOAT => (float)BitConverter.ToSingle(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.BYTE => (byte)contentData[i],
    DataContentType.SHORT => (short)BitConverter.ToInt16(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.INTEGER => (int)BitConverter.ToInt32(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.LONG => (long)BitConverter.ToInt64(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    _ => throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid data type"),
};
```

Now, in case when `header.DataContentType` is `DataContentType.INTEGER`, the value gets assigned as a double to `value` instead of as an `int` and `(int)value` causes an InvalidCastException

If I debug I can clearly see that it steps into the `INTEGER` case, and if I evaluate `BitConverter.ToInt32(currentValueBytes.ToArray())` in the debug console I get an integer returned. However, as soon as the switch case is exited the variable `value` is of type double.

Further, if I manually do `value = BitConverter.ToInt32(currentValueBytes.ToArray())` the variable is of the correct type `int`. Implying the switch statement has to change the type to double for some weird reason.

I would like the switch case to return whatever type the `BitConverter` returns. How can I make the `BitConverter` return the type of the correct BitConverter case?

Comment: What are `header` and `DataContentType` and `currentValueBytes` (and perhaps `contentData`)? Also can you add some samples, please?

Comment: Basically I am parsing a file, in which header it says of which type the data in the file is. I just use it to correctly parse the data into its correct type

Comment: @RononDex I'm sorry but I understand nothing. Perhaps you talk about some techs and some commonly known classes which seems trivial to you, which I don't know.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I was noticing the swith statement always returning a double, instead of integer, or whatever the current case was. I was just trying to put my throught process into words, on why it has to be the switch statement that messes something up and I am not sure why

Comment: @RononDex Check the values of the various `DataContentType.DOUBLE`, `DataContentType.INTEGER` and so on... perhaps there is a typo. Or put a breakpoint on the first line of the `switch` and press F10 and see where it goes. When you put the breakpoint, in VS2019 it will "illuminate" the whole block perhaps, but the F10 and the F11 will step on the right row.

Comment: @xanatos thats exactly what I did, it went into the INTEGER case correctly and parsed the value correctly. It even assigns the correct int value but assigns it as a double for some weird reason. (Sorry if that was not clear from my question)

Comment: @RononDex I'm sorry but without exposing what are header and DataContentType and currentValueBytes (and perhaps contentData), and also without sample data, what can we do to help you, even on such a simple and elementary switch?

Comment: @OlivierRogier you can reproduce it by running this unit test (or debugging) here: https://github.com/RononDex/FitsLibrary/blob/b3ddb493c9c3bc024a8105643e79668196893308/FitsLibrary.Tests/Deserialization/ContentDeserializerTests.cs#L33

Comment: You don't need all those casts.  `BitConverter.ToInt32` returns an `int`, you don't need to cast it to an `int`.  If you are saying that this expression ( `(int)BitConverter.ToInt32(currentValueBytes.ToArray()` ) throws an invalid cast, then something is very wrong.  I'd try doing a Build->Clean and a Rebuild.

Comment: @xanatos Actually, a `switch` expression returns the "best" type from the collection of types from all cases. It always has a single return type.

Comment: It would make more sense (to me, at least) to cast everything to `object` so that everything coming out of the individual switch cases is the same type

Comment: @Flydog57 I know, just added those casts to be sure it returns the correct type

Comment: @xanatos that means in my case it simply returns the first type it finds in the switch expression? That would mean the type of the switch expression is defined at compile time, not at runtime is that correct?

Comment: Not the first; the widest. It just so happens that the first is also the widest. All types you have there can be implicitly widened to `double`.

Comment: @Flydog57 just tried your idea! it works :) if I cast everything to object I can then correctly cast the value to int afterwards. If you post that as an answer I am glad to mark it as a answer :)

Comment: Correct, the type of a `switch` expression is defined at compile time. Unfortunately that is not clearly documented.

Comment: what I do not understand though, in what way is this a low quality question?

Comment: @NetMage thats good to know, I guess learning by trial and error will stick with me for the rest of my programming career xD

Comment: Note that just one cast to `object` is enough to force the whole `switch` expression to return `object` as that is "better" than any numeric type for all the cases. But not a great way to code :)

Comment: Funny thing is, Roslyn is shouting at me "(object) cast is not needed". Even though it actually is in this case

Comment: @NetMage I stand corrected... I've done a more extensive analysis and it is funny (where funny means "it seems the nightmare of a programmer more than the specification of a language")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure things will work better if every case in a `switch` expression returns a consistent type.  They casts you show are superfluous.  Each of those BitConverter calls returns the type you expect.

But, remember, each of those things ends up being boxed as an `object` at some point in your code.  It's probably better if you specify when and how that boxing takes place.  Consider something like this instead:

```
object value = header.DataContentType switch
{
    DataContentType.DOUBLE => (object)BitConverter.ToDouble(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.FLOAT => (object)BitConverter.ToSingle(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.BYTE => (object)contentData[i],
    DataContentType.SHORT => (object)BitConverter.ToInt16(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.INTEGER => (object)BitConverter.ToInt32(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    DataContentType.LONG => (object)BitConverter.ToInt64(currentValueBytes.ToArray()),
    _ => throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid data type"),
};
```

I'm intrigued how you are going to consume `value` at this point.  Unboxing is a delicate operation.  The only time I've ever done something like this is upstream of a JSON-ification operation (where the Newtonsoft JSON package if very happy serializing boxed native value types).

Comment: I just found that just using `var value = ...` instead of `object value = ...` makes the `(object)` casts inside the switch obsolete. Personally I find that the nicer solution because it leaves cleaner code, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: And to answer your quesiton, I am parsing a file format that can hold data in different types (double, single, int, etc). The only way I found to deal with this was to use `object` and then have a function "AsInt()" or something to access the data on the consumer side

Comment: it is kinda weird when you think about, declaring the variable `object`causes it to become a `double` but declearing it as a `var` makes it a `object`. :D

Comment: No, the declaration of the variable on the left-hand side of the assignment has nothing to do with the type of the right-hand side. The only relationship comes with the decision "can the RHS be assigned to the LHS" and "if the types differ, is there an implicit conversion from the RHS to the type of the LHS". I think the problem you were running into is similar to the weirdnesses you get when you have a ternary operator and the types of the two options differ (`condition ? oneType : otherType`).  The rules there are confusing.  I have no idea about the rules for switch expressions- they're new

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `switch` expression with an actual `switch` statement assigning `value`. A `switch` expression has a single return type that is the "best" type from all the types of the cases, and you will get a compiler error when there is no "best" type. So every case is converted to that "best" type.

Comment: Only if they are all implicitly castable, otherwise it will try to box... But only if the result variable is explicitly `object`... otherwise it will throw an error... This will box: `object res = val switch { 1 => 1.0, 2 => 1M }`, this won't compile: `var res = val switch { 1 => 1.0, 3 => 1M };`, and this `var res = val switch { 1 => 1.0, 2 => 1L }` and this `object res = val switch { 1 => 1.0, 2 => 1L }` will cast to `double`. Clearly this too will box: `object res = val switch { 1 => 1.0, 2 => 2L, 3 => "" }` and this won't compile  `var res = val switch { 1 => 1.0, 2 => 2L, 3 => "" }`

Comment: If you can add the fix with casting it to `object` inside the switch case I will be happy to accept this as an answer.

Comment: @RononDex Not my answer :)